# Windows 7: Rename items in taskbar jumplists without renaming the actual file

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, rename, jumplist

TL;DR: I want to be able to change the name of items in the Windows 7 taskbar without changing the name of the file they link to.

---

Using ZIM Desktop Wiki I want to pin my notebooks to the taskbar icon for ZIM in order to be able to skip the "Open Notebook dialog", instead keeping links to the `notebook.zim` files in the jumplist.

Sadly however, this doesn't seem to be reasonably possible. I can pin `notebook.zim` files to the taskbar, but if I rename them (rightclick → Properties) the name of the original file is changed -- but the program requires the file to be called `notebook.zim`.

When pinning items to the start menu, a common trick is to pin a custom-named link to the file to the startmenu instead. If I try this with the jumplist however, the link will be resolved and again `notebook.zim` will be displayed and renaming it will again change the name of the original file, which must not be changed.

So I cannot find a way to add distinguishable items for ZIM or programs with similiar multi-file formats to the taskbar jumplist.

Answer (score 2):

Create a shortcut to the files or containing folder and rename that. You can then create a new toolbar in your Windows taskbar that points to a folder containing all of your shortcuts for an easy 'jump list'.

Comment: Nice, but...ugh, this is such a hack. I read the first three words of your answer and promptly rushed off to create shortcuts to the dirs I wanted pinned, only to discover that the names in the "pinned" list are the names of the dereferenced shortcut targets. I'm sure there's a good implementation reason for this, but it's pretty annoying.